# how to access puppet variable in custom facts?

Tags: puppet

I am extracting a zip at a location, in extracted folder directory there is a *install*.jar.I want to copy a file to the directory where install.jar is available. Now the zip I am extracting may have different folder structure every time, because of this I can not use  
`file{'EXTRACTED_PATH/ant.properties':
ensure: present
}`

So I wrote a custom fact that will find out path of a install jar & I accessed value in manifest like
`$install_jar_location=$::getinstallerpath`

Now in facts file I have to give path to search, this path I want to pass as a parameter.

for that I have declared one variable in manifest file

```
$installer_location="/home/oracle/Installer"
```

how can I access it in my custom fact.
I tried to do following but `$installer_location`variable value is coming up blank.

`Facter.add(:getinstallerpath) do
  setcode do
     Facter::Util::Resolution.exec("echo \"$(dirname \"$(find $installer_location  -name \*install*.jar)\")\"   ")
  end
end`

Comment: You cannot do this. Would you like to edit the question to a higher level so that the true problem can be solved?

Comment: To expand: fact implementations are completely evaluated, on the client, *before* catalog building.  The resulting fact values are inputs to the catalog-building process, on the server, along with the manifest files.  Fact values are thus determined before manifest evaluation starts, so nothing in your manifests can affect them.

Comment: @MattSchuchard I have updated my question, hope this will give better idea.